# Grouping sums in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I'm currently doing dissertation work which requires me to average 95 pieces of tidal data for a month. I have all my data, but averaging them is turning out to be a tedious pain.

I have 95 points I want to average together, then moving on to the next day's data. So, at the moment, my equations are like such =SUM(D12:D107)/95, then =SUM(D108:205)/95, and so on.

Is there a way to make Excel automatically clump the next 95 pieces of data rather than having to manually select the group of cells? I have to do this for about twenty different locations, so having a quicker way of doing it would be useful!

I know I probably haven't explained it very well...

Comment: Is there a date in another column?  You could use an `averageif` function or a pivot table to display the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `indirect()`.
Assuming you keep the starting row at cell `A1` and the equation at cell `B1`.  Then at `A1` you can enter 12, and at cell `B1` enter the formula

```
=average(indirect("D"&A1&":D"&A1+95))
```

`"D"&A1&":D"&A1+95` evaluates to a string "D12:D107", which in turns converted into the range "D12:D107" understandable by Excel through `indirect()`.

Here, I replaced your `sum()/95` into `average()` to make it cleaner and more robust.  Please also check again your formula as D12:D107 contains 96 items instead of 95.